# Using jupyter notebook shortcuts in colaboratory

Tags: jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

Is there an easy way to use the default jupyter notebook shortcuts instead of the ones that come as default in colab?

It also appears that hotkeys don't distinguish whether a cell is active or not, which makes the use of simple hotkeys (e.g. 'b'-> insert cell after) impossible.

Any suggestions as to how this can be overcome, or will we have to get used to (slightly) different shortcuts?

Comment: I guess only possible way is to change the default keyboard shortcuts to the one you want or with that of jupyter notebook.

Comment: like you can chage default shortcut for `insert code cell below` by simple `b` and you are good to go.

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't work because the shortcuts don't distinguish between whether you're in edit or command mode. Hence, just typing this comment would have inserted two new cells.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This isn't currently supported in Colab -- [this issue](https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues/75) is the one to follow.

Answer (score 7):

You can edit the existing shortcuts or set new ones by following the steps below:

1. from to menu select Tools and then "Keyboard shortcuts" (or you can use Ctrl+M H shortcut),
2. this will open Keyboard Preferences box,
3. Now you can edit the shortcuts or set new ones,
4. Once you are done, you can press the "SAVE" button to save your preferences.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Use Ctrl+Shift+P and it would give you search bar and its easy from there.

Answer (score -2):

Yes there is. Check here: https://medium.com/@tuewithmorris/google-colab-notebooks-keyboard-shortcuts-aa6a008fb91b

```
Description, Keyboard Shortcut, Jupyter shortcut
show keyboard shortcuts Ctrl/Cmd M H    H
Insert code cell above  Ctrl/Cmd M A    A
Insert code cell below  Ctrl/Cmd M B    B
Delete cell/selection   Ctrl/Cmd M D    DD
Interrupt execution Ctrl/Cmd M I    II
Convert to code cell    Ctrl/Cmd M Y    Y
Convert to text cell    Ctrl/Cmd M M    M
Split at cursor Ctrl/Cmd M -    Ctrl Shift -
```

Comment: The questioner wants to use jupyter notebook shortcuts in Google Colab.  The post you quoted just shows the correspondence between the two.